# Cannot access the Parent field values from list<sObject> and Database.query

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, dynamic-apex

I have a dynamic SOQL that is being generated and then I am using `database.query(querystring)` to store the list of sObject in the dynamic sobject list.

Here's the code :

```
string queryString ='SELECT id';             
        for(string s : fieldNames){
            queryString += ', '+s;
        }
        system.debug('Case Id :'+objid);
        queryString += ' FROM ' + objName + ' WHERE id=\''+objId+'\'';

        system.debug('Query : '+queryString);

        List<sObject> results = Database.query(queryString);
```

this is the query it prints in dev console :

```
SELECT id, Case.Contact.FirstName, Case.Account.Name, Case.Account.website_active__c FROM Case WHERE id='5000R000005XydT'
```

the query here is for Case object but it can be any object that the query runs for. The results variable assignment looks like this:

```
23:11:01:062 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [41]|results|[{"Id":"5000R000005XydTQAS","ContactId":"0030R00000flV9jQAE","AccountId":"0010R00000YyS2lQAF","RecordTypeId":"012o0000000ttBUAAY","Contact":{"Id":"0030R00000flV9jQAE","FirstName":"Test","RecordTypeId":"012o0000000tpuTAAQ"},"Account":{"Id":"0010R00000YyS2lQAF","Website_Active__c":"www.mercermarketplac (2..
```

When I iterate over the results it throws and error `variable not exist`

```
for(sObject s : results){
    system.debug(s.contact.name);
 }
```

How can I access the Contact and Account values if results is not null with `list<sObject>`, or can I not do that and have to make sure to declare the list with that particular sobject being queried like in this case `list<case>`?

I have referred to [this question and](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249042/soql-getting-the-grandparent-of-an-account-from-contact) , [this question.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57560/soql-not-displaying-all-the-fields-requested-relation-fields) But the difference is, they have requested to see fields for a specific object query always. I have a dynamic query which can be for any object, how can I retrieve those values using `list<sObject>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to get a parent sObject, you need to use getSobject, and to get a field from that, use get:

```
for(sObject s : results){
    system.debug(s.getSObject('Contact').get('Name'));
    system.debug(s.getSObject('Contact').getSObject('Account').get('Name'));
}
```

To do this dynamically, you'll probably want to write a generic method:

```
public static Object getValue(SObject record, String path) {
  try {
    SObject temp = record;
    String[] parts = path.split('\\.');
    while(parts.size() > 1) {
      temp = temp.getSObject(parts.remove(0));
    }
    return temp.get(parts[0]);
  } catch(Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

This code should extract a value, or null if there isn't one:

```
for(sObject s : results){
    system.debug(getValue(s, 'Contact.Name'));
    system.debug(getValue(s, 'Contact.Account.Name'));
}
```

Comment: let me try this out, Thanks much for explaining much clearly.

Comment: this worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: if I have 3 levels then this is returning null, like if I need a field  `Docman_Communication__c.PrimaryInformation__r.Account.Website_Active__c` and here when we get Contact it also has Account as an ID and the `getValue()` method has to be called agian, but how do I avoid that recursive and get value from account?

Comment: @apple123 You'd need to have gotten the record in to a variable. The recursion is necessary otherwise.

Comment: @sfdcfox I am using the same method and trying to get the value from grandparent. But I am getting error. String field = 'Learning_Community__r.Site_Leader__r.MATCH_User_Id_Auto__c';
List<String> fields = field.split('\\.');
List<sObject> acc = [SELECT Learning_Community__r.Site_Leader__r.MATCH_User_Id_Auto__c FROM Engagement__c WHERE Learning_Community__r.Site_Leader__c!=null LIMIT 1 ];
for(sObject s : acc){
    system.debug(MATCH_MatchesDataReviewStudent.getValue(s, field));
    //system.debug(s.getSobject('Learning_Community__r').getsObject('Site_Leader__r'));
}

Comment: I am getting this error "System.SObjectException: Invalid relationship Site_Leader__r for Engagement__c"

Comment: @sfdcfox: I figured out, one issue in the method ---- temp = record.getSObject(parts.remove(0));, it has to be temp = temp.getSObject(parts.remove(0));

Comment: @Ajay Yes, you're right, I didn't test it with multiple relationships. Thanks for the notification! I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Apex is a strongly-typed language. When you have a variable the compiler knows to be a `List<sObject>`, it will only allow you to access fields on the individual `sObject` components of that list that are defined for the `sObject` class - which doesn't include Contact and Account-specific fields. That's why you receive a

> Variable does not exist

error.

You have two options, one static and the other dynamic.

The first is to assign the result, or cast it, to a concrete type:

```
List<Contact> contacts = (List<Contact>)results;
```

That will fail at runtime with an exception if the list *isn't really a `List<Contact>`*.

The other is to use dynamic methods. With an `sObject` variable, you may call the method [`get()` to obtain a field value, and `getSobject()` for a related object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#!).

Note that `get()` returns an even more generic value - an `Object`. You'll again have to cast this to a concrete type to do much with it. `getSobject()` returns an `sObject` that acts the same as the ones you've already got, except that its actual underlying type may be different. For example, if you did `someCase.getSobject('Contact')`, your sObject returned would actually be a `Contact` - but the compiler doesn't know that at compile time.

Comment: Thank you, I will be sure to try out this. @sfdcfox has also responded, I will try that out too.

Answer (score -1):

In the case of multiple related sObjects you need to grab the last Sobject. In the below code, if you want HealthCloudGA__MedicalRecordNumber__pc which is a field of Person Account, then you need to traverse from Medical_note__c >> Case >> Account >> HealthCloudGA__MedicalRecordNumber__pc.

```
String tQue = 'select Id,Case__r.Account.HealthCloudGA__MedicalRecordNumber__pc,CreatedDate from Medical_Note__c where Id =: newID limit 1';

Medical_Note__c tnote = Database.query(tQue);              

String medRecordNumber = (String)tnote.Case__r.Account.get('HealthCloudGA__MedicalRecordNumber__pc');
```